# add PPA failed in Docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt

I ran **add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa** in docker container, but failed with the notice:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ppaname/ppa'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is crrect.
```

Hower it worked on the host.

After googled a lot，I've tried the followings:

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

and didn't work.

The system on host is ubuntu 14.04,64bit.

The image of container is based on ubuntu 14.04 from DOCKER HUB.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure what went wrong with you.

Here's how I got it working:

```
$ docker run -t -i --rm ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash

And inside the container
# apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
# add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
# apt-get update
```

Comment: I solved this problem. The image of container is based on Debian wheezy, not ubuntu. I made a fool mistake.

Comment: In my case `apt-get install -y software-properties-common` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining this var before

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run an early `apt-get update` to get my PPA working inside my dockerfile.

```
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
    #...time passes...
    RUN add-apt-repository -y 'ppa:openjdk-r/ppa' && apt-get update
```